# Extra Space appearing on zoom out of mobile web page, Galaxy S5

Tags: android, html, css, responsive-design, galaxy

I am trying to create a responsive site for my client, but they are complaining that the user can zoom out and see white space on the edge of the screen. It's happening on iPhone 6, but I only have a Galaxy S5 to debug with, and it's happening there, on all browsers, too.

My HTML viewport meta looks like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

My CSS query looks like

```
@-webkit-viewport{
        width:device-width;
        zoom: 1.0;
    }
    @-moz-viewport{
        width:device-width;
        zoom: 1.0;
    }
    @-ms-viewport{
        width:device-width;
        zoom: 1.0;
    }
    @-o-viewport{
        width:device-width;
        zoom: 1.0;
    }
    @viewport{
        width:device-width;
        zoom: 1.0;
    }



@media screen and (max-width: 768px),
    only screen and (-Webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (-Webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (-Webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
    only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
        body {
            font-family: 'Roboto', Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
    }
```

Anyone know where this space is coming from and how I can make it go away

Thanks

[image: screenshot of portrait site with viewport meta tag]

[image: screenshot of landscape site with viewport meta tag]

[image: screenshot of landscape site with no viewport meta tag]

Answer (score 0):

The issue actually wound up being deep inside the html and css. The buttons on the homepage had `position: absolute` and `transform: translate(-75%, -50%)` (and all the prefixes...), and were causing the extra space.

I changed them to `position: relative;` and set the positioning with `margin-top: 10%; margin-right: 15%`.

It looks great now.